# Unix: Adding and indenting using the sed command

Tags: unix, sed

What command could I write in one line that would turn this text:

```
apple
blueberry
raspberry
strawberry
blackberry
mango
orange
```

into this:

```
apple
berries:
   blueberry
   raspberry
   strawberry
   blackberry
mango
orange
```

Comment: Where's the indentation?

Comment: Where did the `berries:` come from? Could you explain to us the logic you want to implement? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a simplistic level, this does more or less what you ask:

```
grep -v "berry" original.txt; echo "berries:"; sed -ne '/berry/s/^/   /p' original.txt
```

**Sample Output**

```
apple
mango
orange
berries:
   blueberry
   raspberry
   strawberry
   blackberry
```

That says... find all the lines NOT containing *"berry"* in `original.txt` because `grep -v` is a negative search. Then it prints the title *"berries"*. Then it starts a new `sed` with `-n` so that, by default, it prints nothing. On lines matching *"berry"*, it replaces the start of line with 3 spaces and then prints the line with `p`.

It will find *"loganberry"*, but it won't work as expected if *"strawberries"* appears in the original. It will also print the *"berries:"* title even if there are no berries in the file...

Answer (score 0):

let your source file be ***input.txt***

we can use below code to add a ***tab*** at starting of each line which contain the string ***berry***

```
sed '/berry/s/^/\t/' input.txt
```

optionally, use ***-i*** option to change the source file itself,

```
sed -i '/berry/s/^/\t/' input.txt
```

Then to add heading ***berries:*** we can use below,

```
sed 's/berry/berries:\n&/g' input.txt
```

Note : assuming the input file is sorted so all berries are in adjacent lines.